# Override Field Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, overriding, virtual

I must be going wrong somewhere in my approach but I'm struggling to find where.
I'm using .NET MVC.

I have a base class (base form model) with an email address field:

```
    public abstract class BaseFormModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Email address")]
        [RegularExpression(Constants.ValidationPatterns.Email, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid {0}")]
        [RequiredIf("SignUpForEmailUpdates", true, RequiredErrorMessage)]
        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 250 characters")]
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

And a have a another class that inherits from this (specific form model) with an override email address field:

```
    public class ContactFormModel : BaseFormModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Email address")]
        [RegularExpression(Constants.ValidationPatterns.Email, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Email")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50 characters")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
        public override string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my view I have:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @type = "email" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
```

The textbox that is displayed on the webpage has the [RequiredIf] parameters applied to it when I don't want it to and have attempted to override it to stop it displaying this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Most likely `m` here is the base type, and the supplier of validation attributes for `ValidationMessageFor`. Note that the string in `EmailAddress` has none of these attributes so the only way for it to obtain those attributes is if `m => m.EmailAddress` doesn't just return the property value but *is* the property, and thus that has to be an expression. If the expression is `(basetype m) => m.EmailAddress` then i can easily see why this would what you're saying it does.

Comment: You are not actually overriding the `RequiredIf` decorator.

Comment: @4ndy You were right, if you want to just copy and paste your comment into an answer I will happily mark it as correct. Only a year late!

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen if you could unmark this as duplicate please it would be appreciated as the answer in the post you marked as duplicate does not answer this question. Many thanks

Comment: @benmurphy it won't let me post an answer because it is closed, but I thank you for the follow up.